# Why autocovariance is 0?

Tags: time-series, self-study

First of all I am a newbie in stats, trying to study statistics, and somehow I find 'time series' way more difficult than other topics.

I am confused with the “autocovariance”. In the book "Time series analysis and its applications", it says:

[image]

Before my question I must admit that I did not know what values of  $w_s$ and $w_t$ shall be chosen, and what I understood from my previous question is that you have to specify a lag: [logic of autocovariance in time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/425383/logic-of-autocovariance-in-time-series)

ie: lag 1 is to compare each value with the one right before.

But now I have 2 questions:

- Why the author never defines the lag he is using? is he calculating the autocovariance for lag 1,2? or what?
- I do not see how the covariance would be 0... If I think of the case for lag 1, in my head I picture potential values like: -0.5,  1, -2, 1, 1.

I see that the autocovariance will be negative (one value goes up, the next one goes down...)

Of course I do know my logic is faulty, the author shall not be wrong, but I want to fully understand it before proceeding to other topics... How come it is 0?

Comment: If $s=t$ the lag is 0, both $s$ and $t$ is time index so when given that $s=t$ then $cov(w_s,w_t) = cov(w_t,w_t) = var(w_t)$. If they are different $s\not=t$ the lag is different from 0 and hence you are looking at different timeperiods, but a white noise process is per definition one where there is no correlation across time that is where $cov(w_s,w_t) = 0 $ follows from $s \not = t$.

Comment: The lag is $s-t.$  By *fiat* the covariance is zero for nonzero lags.

Answer (score 1):

In the example they refer to white noise time-series, so the "random" one, where there is no correlation by definition, since the values are independent of each other.